# Trying to register an application for Power BI

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi

I'm trying to follow the tutorial: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-walkthrough-push-data/ 
and I already stuck on the first step. I go to https://dev.powerbi.com/apps in order to receive client id, I click "Sign in", asked for a power bi login, and then nothing works. The page stays the same, all fields are inactive, and clicking on "Sign in" more does nothing.

1) Anybody can explain what's happening?

2) Is there other way to register an app (receive client id)?

My ultimate goal to write a console app that pushes data inside Power Bi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have figured this out. I went to Azure -> Active Directory -> New, and created an app from there. Also I had to add the permissions for Power Bi Service separately